# React: Importing the State from one Component into another Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

The `Link` component is loaded into the `Foot` component (seen at the bottom).

What I want to happen is for the `Content` component to load the initial state, and change the state as the user clicks the appropriate button.

I can't seem to change the state unless it's within the same component, but having that state load into a `ul` is pretty weird.

**Link Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Home from './Home';
import Characters from './Characters';
import Plot from './Plot';
import Scenes from './Scenes';
import Notes from './Notes';

class Link extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {page: <Home />}
  }

  loadPage = (page) => {
    this.setState({page: page})
  }

  render() {
    const links = [
      {
        title: 'Home',
        page: <Home />
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Characters',
        page: <Characters />
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Plot',
        page: <Plot />
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Scenes',
        page: <Scenes />
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Notes',
        page: <Notes />
      }
    ]

    const link = links.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index}>
          <button onClick={() => this.loadPage(item.page)}>
            {item.title}
          </button>
        </li>
        )
    })
    return (
      <ul className="Link">
        {link}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Link;
```

**Content Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Link from './Link';

class Content extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Content">
        {/*this.state.page goes here*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

**Foot Component** (not that relevant, but the general links will go here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Link from './Link'

class Foot extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <footer className="Foot">
        <Link />
      </footer>
    );
  }
}

export default Foot;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest react version you can use React context to pass the data.

```
const {Provider, Consumer} = React.createContext(defaultValue);
```

Use the provider in your Link component.

```
<Provider value={/* some value */}>
```

Use the consumer in your content component.

```
<Consumer>
  {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
</Consumer>
```

For more details take a look at official documentation.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `Props` to push the links clicked up to the parent.
So for the following example I am assuming that the Content is going to be the parent Component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Home from './Home';
import Characters from './Characters';
import Plot from './Plot';
import Scenes from './Scenes';
import Notes from './Notes';

class Link extends Component {
  // this.props.menuClicked(item.page) 
  // hits the menuClicked props of Foot Component
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="Link">
        {links.map( (item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={ index }>
              <a href="#" onClick={ () => this.props.menuClicked(item.page) }>
                { item.title }
              </a>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Link;
```

And Foot component is the parent of Link Component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Link from './Link'
class Foot extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.loadPage = this.loadPage.bind(this)
  }

  loadPage = (page) => {
    // notice this also pushes the page clicked up to the parent component which is 
    // the Content Component
    this.props.changePage(page);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <footer className="Foot">
        <Link menuClicked={ () => this.loadPage(page) } />
      </footer>
    );
  }
}

export default Foot;
```

And the main parent (Grandparent of Link Component) is going to be the Content Component.

```
// Content
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Home from './Home';
import Characters from './Characters';
import Plot from './Plot';
import Scenes from './Scenes';
import Notes from './Notes';
import Link from './Link';

class Content extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    // default page
    this.state = { page: 'Home' }
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
  }
  // called everytime the Link is clicked
  changePage(newPage) {
    this.setState({
      page: newPage
    })
  }

  render() {
    const links = [
      {
        title: 'Home',
        page: <Home />
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Characters',
        page: <Characters />
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Plot',
        page: <Plot />
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Scenes',
        page: <Scenes />
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Notes',
        page: <Notes />
      }
    ];
    let contentToLoad = null,
      pageToLoad = this.state.page;
    links.forEach( (item) => {
      if (item.title == pageToLoad) {
        contentToLoad = item.page;
      }
    });

    return (
      <div className="Content">
        { contentToLoad }
        <Footer changePage={ this.changePage } />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

Based on the link that is clicked in the Link Component, the corresponding content will be loaded in the Content Component. As you can see the Foot Component is just passing what the Link Component is pushing up to the Content Component, you can either do away with the Foot Component altogether or use what @ShubamGupta has proposed, that is using Context APIs.
With ContextAPIs you can have a Provider and a Consumer, and if you follow the link that he has sent, you will be able to pass content directly from the Link Component to the Content Component.

Comment: **Content** and **Foot** are actually siblings, but **Link** is the child of **Foot**

Comment: In that case, **Link** will have to push the selection up to the Parent of **Foot**, and that parent would push the choice of page down to **Content** or better yet, send the page as children to **Content** 
`<Content>{ pageToLoad }</Content>` and the **Content** component just renders the children as `render() { return (<div>{ this.props.children }</div> }`